# addition and output in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having problems in a loop i'm working on, I'm trying to create a loop that iterates though a value one and it minuses -212.5 then the result should appear as -212.5,-425,-637.5 and -850(being the end point) The code I've written is

```
for(var value1=0; value1>-851; value1--){
    value1-=212.5
    console.log(value1)
}
```

and the output I'm getting

```
-212.5
-426
-639.5 
-853
```

Could somebody kindly assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're subtracting 1 each time through the loop - that's what the `value1--` in the loop header does - in addition to subtracting 212.5 inside it.

Just do your subtraction in one place. Eg by letting the loop do all the work:

```js
for (var value1 = 0; value1 > -851; value1 -= 212.5){
    console.log(value1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I wasn't seeing my mistake... It works now

Answer (score 0):

You are always subtracting `1` here: `value1--`. Maybe you want to replace `value1--` with `value1-=212.5` instead, or you can leave the third part empty.

```js
for(var value1=0; value1>-851; value1-=212.5){
    console.log(value1)
}
```